# tmux: how to bind a key to launch shell command?

Tags: linux, shell, vim, tmux

I use `tmux` to develop, with two panes: one to edit the code, and one to compile it. 
I need to switch pane very often to launch the compile command (say "`mvn install`").
How can I bind a key (say "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>") to launch that specific command in the other pane (or without any pane at all)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`C-b c` already has a standard binding which it might be wise to leave unchanged. Choosing another character, eg <kbd>C-b C</kbd> you can setup a binding in your 
`~/.tmux.conf` file as follows:

```
bind C send-keys -t.- 'mvn install' Enter
```

The `-t.-` means "the other pane". `Enter` stands for the key of that name, i.e. the newline at the end of the command.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I learned that it also prints the command to the terminal pane due.

Answer (score 17):

The right answer to this question is: use `bind-key`, e.g.:

```
tmux bind-key "$KEY" run-shell "/path/to/script.sh"
```

where `KEY=C` in your case.

Comment: Thanks. It's not clear to me where the command will be run? In which pane will be the output?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. [meuh's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283767/162568) works but it simulates real human interaction, thus results in printing the command into the terminal pane.